# Redirect RSS feed with query string via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rss

I keep trying to do a 301 redirect for my RSS feed but it never works. I would like to redirect :

```
http://www.oldsite.com/spip.php?page=backend
```

to :

```
http://rss.newsite.com/rss/55
```

Does anybody knows how do do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's strictly `backend` -> `55` then you just need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=backend$
RewriteRule ^/?spip\.php$ http://rss.newsite.com/rss/55 [L,R=301]
```

in the htaccess file in the document root of your `www.oldsite.com` site.

If it's any more complicated than that, as in the `page=XXX` could be anything, and that `XXX` maps to all kinds of different number other than `55`, then your webserver has no idea what this mapping is and you'll need to explicitly define each redirect like the above one for each of your pages.

Comment: Great! It's exactly what I needed, as it's strictly 'backend' to '55'. Thank you !